# Make TypeScript scripting as fast as Python scripting

Tags: python, typescript, scripting

I am a big fan of TypeScript, and I do not like the weak static analysis of Python because it leads to frequent runtime-crashes of Python programs.
So ideally, I would like to use TypeScript for everything.
However, my biggest gripe with "TypeScript-scripting" is the overhead for small and simple scripts:

- Need to setup a build-system and maintain dependencies.
- Need to maintain configuration for TypeScript and ESLint.
- Need to recompile after every change.

Although recompilation could be avoided with `ts-node`, I have bad experiences with `ts-node` because of its slow startup time.

What I am seeking is a way to make TypeScript-scripting as simple and painless as Python-scripting.
Ideally, I would like to have no compilation and zero compiler-configurations.

My reasoning is that static analysis is a very cheap, efficient and scalable way to prevent bugs, given that the following two preconditions are fulfilled:

- The static checks must be very fast, otherwise the user experience of the scripting language would be destroyed.
- The static checks must have zero or close to zero "false positives", otherwise they could become a productivity-killer instead of a productivity-booster.

Another thing that is important are "strict compilation settings", although I do not want to actually compile anything. Otherwise, the power of TypeScript would be severely diminished.

Comment: So you want compile-time type-checking, but without any actual compilation? Sounds like a contradiction to me. That's one of the inherent trade-offs with static vs dynamic typing.

Comment: This is not necessarily a contradiction. It is very well possible to do static typechecking for scripts, but those checks need to be very fast, otherwise they would destroy the user experience of the scripting language.

Comment: In fact, I believe that every "dynamic language" does a certain amount of static analysis, even if it is only basic syntax-checks. Even the Python-interpreter will need to check the basic structure of a script before it can execute anything. But those primitive syntax-checks are not enough for the usage that I have in mind.